# how to select a string of three random latter starting from a specific letter(for e.g. starting from a ,b or c) in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

how to select a string of three random latter starting from a specific letter(for e.g. starting from a ,b or c) in pl/sql. And also i want to compare this three digit string from my database if it is present or not.

Comment: You need to update your question to provide more information on what you're after - do you have a string that you want to substr, or do you need to generate a string of random letters and then substr in? How do you determine the specfic letter to start from? 1st occurence? 3rd occurrence?. And "compare this three digit string from my database" ... what, you want to search all columns in all tables? Or do you have a specific table and columns in mind?

Comment: I want generate random a three words string(e.g. ACQ) starting from say 'A'. Then i wud lyk to compare it with my existing three words string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace function f_get_random_string(
    p_start_letter in varchar2
)
return varchar2
is
    cursor c_string_exists(
        p_string in varchar2
    )
    is
      select 'Y'
      from dual
      where exists (
                select *
                from my_table
                where my_string = p_string
            );

    l_string        varchar2(3);
    l_string_exists varchar2(1);
begin
    loop
        l_string := p_start_letter || dbms_random.string('U', 2);

        l_string_exists := null;

        open c_string_exists(l_string);
        fetch c_string_exists into l_string_exists;
        close c_string_exists;

        exit when l_string_exists is null;
    end loop;

    return l_string;
end f_get_random_string;
```

---

```
select f_get_random_string('A') as random_string
from dual;
```